# azure aks take backup of mongodb running in k8 cluster to local file or azure storage

Tags: mongodb, azure, kubernetes

**problem statement** 
we want to take backup of mongodb running in k8s cluster in azure and export it in some other mongodb running in differnt k8s cluster.
does any one provide pointers related to this

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a [Kubernetes Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) with Azure file share as the persistent volume. In the cronjob you can run a mongodump command.

You can also use [MGOB](https://github.com/stefanprodan/mgob) which can help to configure scheduled backups as well.

If you have multiple MongoDB instances on kubernetes, I would recommend you to try MGOB. They would greatly simplify the setup.

If you need a solution which you need to implement, you can choose Kubernetes Cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

The following CronJob will create a job that uses the community supported mongo:4.4.0-bionic image to mount the same persistent volume as your mongo server, back it up, and then tar it.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mongodb-backup
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mongodb-backup
            image: mongo:4.4.0-bionic
            args:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - "/usr/bin/mongodump -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD -o /tmp/backup -h mongodb"
            - "tar cvzf mongodb-backup.tar.gz /tmp/backup"
            #- gsutil cp mongodb-backup.tar.gz gs://my-project/backups/mongodb-backup.tar.gz
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
            volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: mongodb-persistent-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mongodb-pv-claim
```